# Testing Downstream GFCI protection

Tags: electrical

I have one garage GFCI protecting 3 bathrooms and 1 outdoor outlet in a 1990 house.   How do I know the 4 downstream outlets are GFCI protected? Is it sufficient to push the GFCI test button and confirm the downstream outlets have no power?

Comment: A 1990 house should have grounds everywhere, so a basic GFCI tester should work on downstream outlets. Those have trouble working where a GFCI is protecting outlets with no ground (which is a very valid use for GFCI)

Answer (score 1):

Invest in a GFCI tester. It will test for polarity and proper grounding of all outlets in addition to testing GFI's. Pressing the button will simulate a grounded circuit and trip the GFI even from the downstream outlets. I included a link to one on Amazon, but any big box store or hardware store will carry them.

[Link](https://www.google.com/search?q=gfco+tester&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS984US985&oq=gfco+tester&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i512l9.1685435084j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I confirmed I have power to all downstream outlets, and the GFCI test button cut power to all.  I need to look at my equipment better as I have a tester I was just using for continuity and polarity, but I see now how the GFCI test button on it works.  Problem solved.  Thanks for the help! Love this site!

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.
First you need to make sure that they had power before. That way you can verify that the outlets are connected to the GFCI and that the GFCI works.

It leaves the possibility of wiring problems (missing ground). That can be verified by an GFCI outlet tester.

At our location we test that by using the low-impedance test of an two pole voltage tester, between hot and ground.